# Flutter, webview_flutter IOS window pop up not working

Tags: ios, flutter, safari

Users must see some pop-up to sign up. (kinda Webview certification)

There is no problem with Android at all, but I don't know if IOS uses the Safari browser, but there is no popup. Anything else, it shows well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In info.plist please include these keys

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: it does not work, somebody saying use nested web view do you know how to do this?( webview and custom webview)

Comment: Please include info.plist in question

Comment: I found out it can`t be done. Because of Apple Systems. Maybe I have to give up

Comment: Appreciate it from my heart it works (but I did other thing also) But lastly, it saved me

Comment: it didn't work for me :(

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @dontknowhy when you say "you did other thing also" are you able to tell us what you did here please so the question is answered? much appreciated.